# how to format string variable to be used in an IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, stored-procedures

This question seems to have been asked several times, and I apologize for having to open another question with a redundant inquiry.

I am struggling implementing every solution I find online regarding this topic.

I have written a SSRS report that passes a string with multiple values to a sql stored procedure.

The string with values look like: 'Ambulance, Metro, Stickers, Gardens'

The stored procedure uses dynamic sql because of some conditions that need to be met in order to run.

The string of values coming from the report, need to be used in an IN operator, but every solution I have tried to implement I get the error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

What I do is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WIP_OnlineInformation]
(
    @s_Group    NVARCHAR(500) = 'ABC,DEF, GHI'
,   @s_Type     NVARCHAR(500) = 'Garden, Metro, Parks, Ambulance'
)

DECLARE @t_Group_Type TABLE
(
    _Group NVARCHAR(500)
,   _Type NVARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO @t_Group_Type   
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Group] = (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@s_TransactionGroup)) 
,   [Type] = (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@s_TransactionType))
```

And that is it, I can not make it pass the error mentioned above.

Here are the contents of the UDF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String NVARCHAR(2000))
RETURNS @List TABLE(ID VARCHAR(100))
AS
    BEGIN
        WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @String) > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @List (ID)
            VALUES(LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX(',', @String) - 1));
            SET @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - CHARINDEX(',', @String));
         END;
     INSERT INTO @List (ID)
     VALUES(@String);
     RETURN;
 END;
```

This is the dynamic query in which I would like to use the values:

```
SET @s_SQL =
    'SELECT' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +        
    '   pu.Source' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    --',    ' + @s_ColumnName  + ' ColX ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.Account' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.Name' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.Amount'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +       
    ',  pu.Status' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.Phone' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.StreetAddress1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.StreetAddress2' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.City' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.[State]' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.ZIP' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ',  pu.Email' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    'FROM ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    '   vwCustomer pu WITH (NOLOCK) ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    ' WHERE'  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    '   pu.Group IN (' + (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@s_TransactionGroup)) + ')'  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    '   AND pu.ype IN (' + (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@s_TransactionType)) + ')' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  I'm also not sure what your question has to do with `IN`.

Comment: Let's simplify things first. Imagine you pass 'abc' as the first param and '11,22' as the second param. Now how do you expect to use those 2 sets of values in your procedure for producing the desired output? I'll guess that you want to compare the set from one param to a column in a select statement and to compare the set from the other param to a very different column in your select statement. You are trying to force a relationship between the two params via the table variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: I added the SELECT statement in which I would like to use the list of values in an IN operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your error by doing:

```
INSERT INTO @t_Group_Type   
    SELECT g.*, t.*
    FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@s_TransactionGroup)) g CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@s_TransactionType)) t;
```

It is not clear if you want a Cartesian product, because you don't actually explain the results that you do want.

Comment: cmon - explain at least a little bit and define where / what dbo.Split does (because it isn't standard tsql functionality)!

Comment: @Smor . . . I'm not sure if you read the question, but the code for `split()` is in the question.  It is the OP's code.  So, if you have a question about it, direct it to the OP.